# Google Play App action bar in Gingerbread

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar, android-2.3-gingerbread

How is it possible for a Google Play App to have ActionBar in GingerBread although Action Bar is supported from Honeycomb onwards.

Comment: http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: so you are saying google used actionbarsherlock?

Comment: Yes, even they use it. Have a look at [iosched on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/#git%2Flibprojects%2Fabs), that's the official app for their dev conference Google I/O. ActionBarSherlock is the defacto standard when you want to implement an ActionBar across all android versions *(which means 2.1+, that is the minimum version for abs)*.

Comment: I get it. Thanks for the link. 
But I am having some serious problems with ABS. Especially while implementing a theme. Can you help me?

Comment: Maybe - certainly not without more details though. I'd say open a dedicated question that states what specific problem you have and what exactly you did to get there.

Comment: I already did. But no one answering. Can you help? Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448679/how-can-i-have-a-drop-shadow-on-my-actionbar-actionbarsherlock